# C++ : How to serialize/deserialize objects to binary archive format using Boost library?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization

I have succeeded to serialize my Employee object into **file format** using **Boost library**, and I want to send it through socket using TCP/IP communication protocol, but I guess that this protocol does not work for files.

I am thinking of **serializing and deserializing the object into binary format** but I did not know how to do it, I did not find examples on the internet, so would you please help me ?

I will share with you my code :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
 
using namespace std;
 
class Employee {
private:
   friend class boost::serialization::access;
   int id;
   string name;
   float salary;
   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive &a, const unsigned version){
      a & id & name & salary;
   }
public:
   Employee(){}
   Employee(int i, string n, float s):id(i),name(n),salary(s)
   {}
};
 
int main()
{
   const string filename = "emp.dat";
   Employee e1(11,"Harry",4500.00f);
   Employee e2(22,"Ravi",8800.00f);
   Employee e3(33,"Tim",6800.00f);
   Employee e4(44,"Rajiv",3400.00f);
 
   // Serialize and persist the object
   {
      std::ofstream outfile(filename);
      boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(outfile);
      archive << e1 << e2 << e3 << e4;
   }
 
   // Deserialize and restore the object
   Employee restored_e1;
   Employee restored_e2;
   Employee restored_e3;
   Employee restored_e4;
 
   {
      std::ifstream infile(filename);
      boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(infile);
      archive >> restored_e1 >> restored_e2
         >> restored_e3 >> restored_e4;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I guess that this protocol does not work for files`, why do you guess we can't send files via TCP? Haven't you download any text from a website?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin yes it does not work for files

Answer (score 0):

[*Summary*]

a) look for a std::stream compatible class that accepts a socket. (I think boost asio has one).

b) create a file handle and assign the socket handle to it.

c) caveat: The boost serialize Archive concept does not lend itself easily to what you are trying to do. See below.

[***Detail***]

Firstoff, what you are asking here has nothing to do with text or binary file format. Either would work in principle with tcp/ip. text serializes your data in human readable (text) form whereas binary would simply replace the readable (text) with a binary representation. This has nothing to do with where the data is going.

That said: What you are trying to do is serialize to a tcp/ip socket instead of a file. This is possible, although it is not immediately obvious how. boost serialize uses an Archive as a wrapper around a std::stream. If you have a stream that writes data to a tcp/ip socket rather than a file, than that would be what you wanted.

[**My recommendation**]

I'll start with c): caveat. The boost Archive concept does not lend itself easily to serialization via sockets. The reason is that usually you have exactly ONE Archive PER FILE. Translated to socket: You can serialize exactly ONE Archive PER Connection. You will have to close the connection and reopen it, if you need to serialize more than one "archive". closing and reopening takes time.

Given the fact that you also don't have a std::otcpstream ready, my own approach was to serialize my Archives to std::o/istringstream and send the entire string buffer via TCP/IP. Like this:

```
   std::ostringstream out;
   {
      boost::text_archive outA(out);
      outA << do some serialization;
   }
   send_via_tcp(out.str());
```

Note: The brackets here are important. The Archive destructor will write an 'end' tag to the stream, so unless the destructor gets called, the `out.str()` call will yield an incomplete string.

[**serializing directly to TCP/IP**]

That said, you could try to serialize directly to TCP/IP. Problem is, there is no std::stream class that serializes to a socket. You'd expect a std::otcpstream for example, but there is none (in std).

a) I think boost asio has a stream that uses TCP/IP so you can look there.

b) The second option is to open a socket and then create a file handle for this socket. The function _dup() accepts a socket as input (I think). That way you have a file handle (rather than a socket) and can create an ofstream/ifstream for it. Or perhaps create the ofstream/ifstream first and reassign the file handle with _dup.

I think this will cause all read/write calls to go to the TCP/IP stack instead of the file system so in theory you should be able to write/read an Archive (exactly one). But like I said above, I'd simply use the stringstream method, if your archives aren't too big.